# Is there a community for beauty tips here?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Would you know if there a beauty community created here? I would love to participate in regards of beauty expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for [lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com).

They have a tag like [personal-care](/questions/tagged/personal-care), [makeup](/questions/tagged/makeup).

But please read [FAQ](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help) before post your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not. And it's very likely there never will be.

> beauty is in the eye of the beholder

And that means that every question about beauty is basically opinion-based, something we try to avoid here.

We strive to provide answers to questions where we can objectively measure, we can somehow prove correct or wrong. Up- or downvoting is not meant to be a popularity contest, but an experts vote on what is known and proven to be working. That concept works very well for the technical sites and you can see it showing it's cracks and ugly faces on sites that handle topics where there rarely is an absolute "right" or "wrong" answer.

So no, there is no such site and the goals and inner workings of Stack exchange do not really align with that topic.

Comment: While I'm the sort of dude who occasionally washes his hair in soap - one of the people I know online kinda does this sorta thing for a living. There's actually a fair amount of skill, training and knowhow involved in doing what she does, and the occational risk of chemical burning your hair off if you mess it up. While at first brush, it seems opinion based, there's probably a fair amount of potentially subjective questions that can be asked, properly scoped, under the surface.

Comment: I'm not saying that "beauty" is something that takes no skill or no technical expertise, but my experience is that even a dozen girls in a highschool class cannot agree on whether *that* exact amount of eyeliner is "too little", "great" or "looks like a sex worker". If even a single highschool class with 2 cliques cannot agree on that topic, how would an international community ever find an objective measure to that question.

Comment: I can absolutely see the lifehacks part from the other answer. Like how to get mascara stains out of a shirt or how to hide a black eye or something. That can objectively be answered, but it isn't exactly "beauty".

Comment: Or more that there's questions *that* actually could have a specific, technical answer. I mean, as tech folks, We can disagree on the merits of RGB lighting, and how it makes my PC look ugly or cool, or have deeply technical conversations over other things.  there is an underlying technique/'technology' behind these things.

Comment: Lets put it this way: I have never seen two tech folks argue about whether the shader is looking to much like a red-light-district. It's always about whether it technically works. I can see professional makeup artists come together and make a great SE site, but I cannot imagine a site about beauty open to the general public. I'm already sick of having general rules imposed to keep sites like IPS in check. "Beauty" would be a nightmare.

Comment: And non technical folks would feel the same of SO, or SO folks of the stwo sites I mod. I suspect a proper subject matter expert would have a different view of this. Neither of us, I think are :D

Comment: The real problem is that "tips" aren't Q&A.